# SWIG and Boost::variant

Tags: python, c++, boost, swig

I'm in the middle of trying to wrap a c++ project into a python api using SWIG and I'm running into an issue with code that has the following format.

```
class A
{
//constructors and such.
};

class B
{
//constructors and such.
};

class C
{
//constructors and such.
};

typedef boost::variant<A,B,C> VariantType;
typedef std::vector<boost::variant<A,B,C>> VariantTypeList;
```

Classes A,B & C all come out in the python wrapper without a problem and seem to be usable. However when I try to add the following lines to the interface file

```
%template(VariantType) boost::variant<A,B,C>;
%template(VariantTypeList) std::vector<boost::variant<A,B,C>>;
```

I get an error that says

> Boost\x64\include\boost\variant\variant.hpp(148): error : Syntax error in input(3).

So I go and look at the error and its a line that has a macro that is defined inside another header file specifically "boost/mpl/aux_/value_wknd.hpp" so I add that to the interface file with %include and now it appears that SWIG.exe crashes with an error helpfully stating

> Access Violation

So long story short is there a way to wrap a boost::variant template type? Unfortunately this template definition is baked into the core of our library and I can't change it now. Also if it matters I'm on the MSVC 2013 compiler.

If it isn't possible to wrap the template type directly is it possible to work around this? I'm reading through the SWIG documentation to see if there is some typemap magic that can be applied but I'm fairly new to SWIG in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. I thought for quite a while about what the neatest Python interface to `boost::variant` actually is. My conclusion was that 99% of the time a Python user shouldn't even realise there's a variant type being use - unions and variants are basically just somewhat constrained duck-typing for C++.

So my goals were this:

- wherever possible benefit from existing typemaps - we don't want to have to write our own `std::string`, `int`, typemaps from scratch.
- anywhere a C++ function takes a `boost::variant` we should transparently accept any of the types the variant can hold for that function argument.
- anywhere a C++ function returns a `boost::variant` we should transparently return it as the type the variant was holding when we got it back into Python.
- allow Python users to explicitly create a variant object, e.g. an empty one, but don't expect that to ever actually happen. (Maybe that would be useful for reference output arguments, but I've not gone that far in this currently).
- I didn't do this, but it would be fairly simple to add visitors from where this interface currently stands using the directors feature of SWIG.

It's pretty fiddly to do all that without adding some machinery into things. I wrapped everything up in a reusable file, this is the final working version of my boost_variant.i:

```
%{
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

static PyObject *this_module = NULL;
%}

%init %{
  // We need to "borrow" a reference to this for our typemaps to be able to look up the right functions
  this_module = m; // borrow should be fine since we can only get called when our module is loaded right?
  // Wouldn't it be nice if $module worked *anywhere*
%}

#define FE_0(...)
#define FE_1(action,a1) action(0,a1)
#define FE_2(action,a1,a2) action(0,a1); action(1,a2)
#define FE_3(action,a1,a2,a3) action(0,a1); action(1,a2); action(2,a3)
#define FE_4(action,a1,a2,a3,a4) action(0,a1); action(1,a2); action(2,a3); action(3,a4)
#define FE_5(action,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) action(0,a1); action(1,a2); action(2,a3); action(3,a4); action(4,a5)

#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,NAME,...) NAME
%define FOR_EACH(action,...)
  GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, FE_5, FE_4, FE_3, FE_2, FE_1, FE_0)(action,__VA_ARGS__)
%enddef

#define in_helper(num,type) const type & convert_type ## num () { return boost::get<type>(*$self); }
#define constructor_helper(num,type) variant(const type&)

%define %boost_variant(Name, ...)

%rename(Name) boost::variant<__VA_ARGS__>;

namespace boost {
  struct variant<__VA_ARGS__> {
    variant();
    variant(const boost::variant<__VA_ARGS__>&);
    FOR_EACH(constructor_helper, __VA_ARGS__);
    int which();
    bool empty();

    %extend {
      FOR_EACH(in_helper, __VA_ARGS__);
    }
  };
}

%typemap(out) boost::variant<__VA_ARGS__> {
  // Make our function output into a PyObject
  PyObject *tmp = SWIG_NewPointerObj(&$1, $&1_descriptor, 0); // Python does not own this object...

  // Pass that temporary PyObject into the helper function and get another PyObject back in exchange
  const std::string func_name = "convert_type" + std::to_string($1.which());
  $result = PyObject_CallMethod(tmp, func_name.c_str(),  "");
  Py_DECREF(tmp);
}

%typemap(in) const boost::variant<__VA_ARGS__>& (PyObject *tmp=NULL) {
  // I don't much like having to "guess" the name of the make_variant we want to use here like this...
  // But it's hard to support both -builtin and regular modes and generically find the right code.
  PyObject *helper_func = PyObject_GetAttrString(this_module, "new_" #Name );
  assert(helper_func);
  // TODO: is O right, or should it be N?
  tmp = PyObject_CallFunction(helper_func, "O", $input);
  Py_DECREF(helper_func);
  if (!tmp) SWIG_fail; // An exception is already pending

  // TODO: if we cared, we chould short-circuit things a lot for the case where our input really was a variant object
  const int res = SWIG_ConvertPtr(tmp, (void**)&$1, $1_descriptor, 0);
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res), "Variant typemap failed, not sure if this can actually happen"); 
  }
}

%typemap(freearg) const boost::variant<__VA_ARGS__>& %{
  Py_DECREF(tmp$argnum);
%}

%enddef
```

This gives us a macro we can use in SWIG, `%boost_variant`. You can then use this in your interface file something like this:

```
%module test

%include "boost_variant.i"

%inline %{
  struct A {};
  struct B {};
%}

%include <std_string.i>
%boost_variant(TestVariant, A, B, std::string);

%inline %{
  void idea(const boost::variant<A, B, std::string>&) {
  }

  boost::variant<A,B,std::string> make_me_a_thing() {
    struct A a;
    return a;
  }

  boost::variant<A,B,std::string> make_me_a_string() {
    return "HELLO";
  }

%}
```

Where the `%boost_variant` macro takes the first argument as a name for the type (much like `%template` would) and the remaining arguments as a list of all the types in the variant.

This is sufficient to allow us to run the following Python:

```
import test

a = test.A();
b = test.B();

test.idea(a)
test.idea(b)

print(test.make_me_a_thing())
print(test.make_me_a_string())
```

---

So how does that actually work?

- We essentially duplicate SWIG's `%template` support here. (It's [documented here as an option](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_template_directive))
- Most of the heavy lifting in my file is done using a `FOR_EACH` variadic macro. Largely that's the same as my [previous answer on `std::function`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32668302/168175), which was itself derived from several older Stack Overflow answers and adapted to work with SWIG's preprocessor.
- Using the `FOR_EACH` macro we tell SWIG to wrap one constructor per type the variant can hold. This lets us explicitly construct variants from Python code, with two extra constructors added
- By using constructors like this we can lean heavily on SWIG's overload resolution support. So given a Python object we can simply rely on SWIG to determine how to construct a variant from it. Which saves us a bunch of extra work, and uses the existing typemaps for each type within the variant.
- The `in` typemap basically just delegates to the constructor, via a slightly convoluted route because it's surprisingly hard to find other functions in the same module programatically. Once that delegation has happened we use the normal conversion of a function argument to just pass the tempoary variant into the function as though it were what we were given.
- We also synthesise a set of extra member functions, `convert_typeN` which internally just call `boost::get<TYPE>(*this)`, where N and TYPE are the position of each type in the list of variant types.
- Within the out typemap this then allows us to lookup a Python function, using `which()` to determine what the variant currently holds. We've then got largely SWIG generated code, using existing typemaps to make a given variant into a Python object of the underlying type. Again that saves us a lot of effort and makes everything plug and play.

Answer (score 1):

If you're decided on SWIG (which wasn't clear to me from your post as you said to be fairly new to SWIG, so I'm under the assumption that this is a new project), then stop reading and ignore this answer.

But in case the bindings technology to use isn't fixed yet and you only need to bind Python, no other languages, an alternative is to use cppyy (http://cppyy.org, and full disclaimer: I'm main author). With that, the boost::variant type is directly available in Python and then you can make it look/behave more Pythonistic by writing Python code rather than SWIG .i code.

Example (note that cppyy has wheels for Windows on PyPI but built with MSVC2017, not MSVC2013, so I'll keep that caveat as to whether MSVC2013 is modern enough to build the code as I haven't tried):

```
import cppyy

cppyy.include("boost/variant/variant.hpp")
cppyy.include("boost/variant/get.hpp")

cpp   = cppyy.gbl
std   = cpp.std
boost = cpp.boost

cppyy.cppdef("""
class A
{
//constructors and such.
};

class B
{
//constructors and such.
};

class C
{
//constructors and such.
};
""")

VariantType = boost.variant['A, B, C']
VariantTypeList = std.vector[VariantType]

v = VariantTypeList()
v.push_back(VariantType(cpp.A()))
print(v.back().which())
v.push_back(VariantType(cpp.B()))
print(v.back().which())
v.push_back(VariantType(cpp.C()))
print(v.back().which())

print(boost.get['A'](v[0]))
try:
    print(boost.get['B'](v[0]))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)   # b/c of type-index mismatch above
print(boost.get['B'](v[1]))  # now corrected
print(boost.get['C'](v[2]))
```

which produces the expect output of:

```
$ python variant.py
0
1
2
<cppyy.gbl.A object at 0x5053704>
Could not instantiate get<B>:
  B& boost::get(boost::variant<A,B,C>& operand) =>
    Exception: boost::bad_get: failed value get using boost::get (C++ exception)
<cppyy.gbl.B object at 0x505370c>
<cppyy.gbl.C object at 0x5053714>
```

Comment: That's pretty neat