# Support for std::tuple in swig?

Tags: swig, stdtuple

When calling a swig generated function returning `std::tuple`, i get a swig object of that `std::tuple`.

Is there a way to use type-maps or something else to extract the values? I have tried changing the code to `std::vector` for a small portion of the code, and that works. (using %include <std_vector.i> and templates) But i don't want to make too many changes in the C++ part.

Edit: here is a minimal reproducible example:

foo.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <tuple>

class foo
{
private:
    double secret1;
    double secret2;
public:
    foo();
    ~foo();
    std::tuple<double, double> return_thing(void);
};
```

foo.cpp

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <tuple>

foo::foo()
{
    secret1 = 1;
    secret2 = 2;
}

foo::~foo()
{
}

std::tuple<double, double> foo::return_thing(void) {
    return {secret1, secret2};
}
```

foo.i

```cpp
%module foo

%{
#include"foo.h"
%}

%include "foo.h"
```

When compiled on my linux using

```
-:$ swig -python -c++ -o foo_wrap.cpp foo.i
-:$ g++ -c foo.cpp foo_wrap.cpp '-I/usr/include/python3.8' '-fPIC' '-std=c++17' '-I/home/simon/Desktop/test_stack_overflow_tuple'
-:$ g++ -shared foo.o foo_wrap.o -o _foo.so
```

I can import it in python as shown:
test_module.ipynb

```py
import foo as f

Foo = f.foo()
return_object = Foo.return_thing()
type(return_object)
print(return_object)
```

Outputs is

```py
SwigPyObject
<Swig Object of type 'std::tuple< double,double > *' at 0x7fb5845d8420>
```

Hopefully this is more helpful, thank you for responding

To clarify i want to be able to use the values in python something like this:

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    foo Foo = foo();
    auto [s1, s2] = Foo.return_thing();
    cout << s1 << " " << s2 << endl;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Github repo if anybody is interested
https://github.com/simon-cmyk/test_stack_overflow_tuple

Comment: make a [mcve]..

Comment: What language are you targeting? The ideal way to wrap a tuple is different depending on the language.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i forgot to mention it. I am using Python

Comment: Added a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Perfect, Python is a simpler one too. I'll try and find some time to write up an answer if nobody else beats me to it

Comment: That would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your helpfulness☺️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our goal is to make something like the following SWIG interface work intuitively:

```c
%module test

%include "std_tuple.i"
%std_tuple(TupleDD, double, double);

%inline %{
   std::tuple<double, double> func() {
       return std::make_tuple(0.0, 1.0);
   }
%}
```

We want to use this within Python in the following way:

```py
import test
r=test.func()
print(r)
print(dir(r))

r[1]=1234

for x in r:
    print(x)
```

i.e. indexing and iteration should just work.

By re-using [some of the pre-processor tricks I used to wrap `std::function`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32668302/168175) (which were themselves originally from another [answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros/11994395#11994395)) we can define a neat macro that "just wraps" `std::tuple` for us. Although this answer is Python specific it should in practice be fairly simple to adapt for most other languages too. I'll post my std_tuple.i file, first and then annotate/explain it after:

```c
// [1]
%{
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
%}

// [2]    
#define make_getter(pos, type) const type& get##pos() const { return std::get<pos>(*$self); }
#define make_setter(pos, type) void set##pos(const type& val) { std::get<pos>(*$self) = val; }
#define make_ctorargN(pos, type) , type v##pos
#define make_ctorarg(first, ...) const first& v0 FOR_EACH(make_ctorargN, __VA_ARGS__)

// [3]
#define FE_0(...)
#define FE_1(action,a1) action(0,a1)
#define FE_2(action,a1,a2) action(0,a1) action(1,a2)
#define FE_3(action,a1,a2,a3) action(0,a1) action(1,a2) action(2,a3)
#define FE_4(action,a1,a2,a3,a4) action(0,a1) action(1,a2) action(2,a3) action(3,a4)
#define FE_5(action,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) action(0,a1) action(1,a2) action(2,a3) action(3,a4) action(4,a5)

#define GET_MACRO(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,NAME,...) NAME
%define FOR_EACH(action,...)
  GET_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__, FE_5, FE_4, FE_3, FE_2, FE_1, FE_0)(action,__VA_ARGS__)
%enddef

// [4]
%define %std_tuple(Name, ...)
%rename(Name) std::tuple<__VA_ARGS__>;
namespace std {
    struct tuple<__VA_ARGS__> {
        // [5]
        tuple(make_ctorarg(__VA_ARGS__));
        %extend {
            // [6]
            FOR_EACH(make_getter, __VA_ARGS__)
            FOR_EACH(make_setter, __VA_ARGS__)
            size_t __len__() const { return std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<decltype(*$self)>>{}; }
            %pythoncode %{
                # [7]
                def __getitem__(self, n):
                    if n >= len(self): raise IndexError()
                    return getattr(self, 'get%d' % n)()
                def __setitem__(self, n, val):
                    if n >= len(self): raise IndexError()
                    getattr(self, 'set%d' % n)(val)
            %}
        }
    };
}
%enddef
```

1. This is just the extra includes we need for our macro to work
2. These apply to each of the type arguments we supply to our `%std_tuple` macro invocation, we need to be careful with commas here to keep the syntax correct.
3. This is the mechanics of our `FOR_EACH` macro, which invokes each action per argument in our variadic macro argument list
4. Finally the definition of `%std_tuple` can begin. Essentially this is manually doing the work of `%template` for each specialisation of `std::tuple` we care to name inside of the std namespace.
5. We use our macro for each magic to declare a constructor with arguments for each element of the correct type. The actual implementation here is the default one from the C++ library which is exactly what we need/want though.
6. We use our `FOR_EACH` macro twice to make a member function `get0`, `get1`, `getN` of the correct type of each tuple element and the correct number of them for the template argument size. Likewise for `setN`. Doing it this way allows the usual SWIG typemaps for `double`, etc. or whatever types your tuple contains to be applied automatically and correctly for each call to `std::get<N>`. These are really just an implementation detail, not intended to be part of the public interface, but exposing them makes no real odds.
7. Finally we need an implementation of `__getitem__` and a corresponding `__setitem__`. These simply look up and call the right `getN`/`setN` function on the class and call that instead. We take care to raise `IndexError` instead of the default exception if an invalid index is used as this will stop iteration correctly when we try to iterate of the tuple.

This is then sufficient that we can run our target code and get the following output:

```
$ swig3.0 -python -c++ -Wall test.i && g++ -shared -o _test.so test_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python3.7 -m32 && python3.7 run.py
<test.TupleDD; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::tuple< double,double > *' at 0xf766a260> >
['__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__swig_destroy__', '__swig_getmethods__', '__swig_setmethods__', '__weakref__', 'get0', 'get1', 'set0', 'set1', 'this']
0.0
1234.0
```

Generally this should work as you'd hope in most input/output situations in Python.

There are a few improvements we could look to make:

1. Implement repr
2. Implement slicing so that `tuple[n:m]` type indexing works
3. Handle unpacking like Python tuples.
4. Maybe do some more automatic conversions for compatible types?
5. Avoid calling `__len__` for every get/setitem call, either by caching the value in the class itself, or postponing it until the method lookup fails?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works good! And unpacking in python seems to work also :)

Comment: But i had to move the // [7] comment out of the % pythoncode %{} scope, in the std_tuple.i file

Comment: D'oh yes, I annotated it after testing, so missed that comment not being a python one.

Comment: It's surprising, however, that this does not come with the "official" SWIG library files. Why do you think this might be so? I'm curious.

Comment: I think two things really: a) there's no built-in version of the `FOR_EACH` and really there probably needs to be and b) much of the SWIG C++ library support pre-dates C++11 and hasn't received many commits recently. I had debated turning this one into a PR, but with something a little better for the `FOR_EACH` and cross-language work as well.